# PHP Objects vs Arrays -- Performance comparison while iterating

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, object

I have a huge amount of PHP objects for a neural network for which I have to iterate over and perform some maths on. I was wondering if I would be better off using an associative array over instances of classes?

I am dealing with around `3640` objects and iterating around `500` times (at best) on top of that so any micro-optimization helps a great deal. Would it inevitably be quicker to do `$object['value']` than `$object->value`?

**Edit:** So they are both the same. But I guess there would be a little overhead for the constructor? Either way I don't think I want to trade in my beautiful classes for dirty arrays :P

Answer (score 69):

Based in the code of Quazzle, i ran the next code (5.4.16 windows 64bits):

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;
    }

function p($i) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($i);
  echo '</pre>';
}


$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=array();
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $z = array();
    for ($j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
        $z['aaa'] = 'aaa';
        $z['bbb'] = 'bbb';
        $z['ccc'] = $z['aaa'].$z['bbb'];            
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>arrays: '.(microtime(true) - $t0)."</p>";
echo '<p>memory: '.($fin-$inicio)."</p>";
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=array();
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $z = new SomeClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>arrays: '.(microtime(true) - $t0)."</p>";
echo '<p>memory: '.($fin-$inicio)."</p>";
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=array();
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $z = new stdClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>arrays: '.(microtime(true) - $t0)."</p>";
echo '<p>memory: '.($fin-$inicio)."</p>";
p($z);  
?>
```

And i obtained the next result:

```
arrays: 1.8451430797577

memory: 460416

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 1.8294548988342

memory: 275696

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 2.2577090263367

memory: 483648

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

Conclusion for php 5.4

1. Class is fasts than Arrays (but marginally).
2. stdClass is evil.
3. Class uses less memory than Arrays. (about 30-40% less!!)

ps: as a note, if the class is defined but the members then, the use of this class is slower.  It also uses more memory.  **Apparently the secret is to define the members**

### Update

I updated from php 5.4 to php 5.5 (5.5.12 x86 windows).

```
arrays: 1.6465699672699

memory: 460400

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 1.8687851428986

memory: 363704

SplFixedArray Object
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 1.8554251194

memory: 275568

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 2.0101680755615

memory: 483656

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

### Conclusion for php 5.5

1. For arrays, PHP 5.5 is faster than PHP 5.4, for object it is pretty much the same
2. Class is slower than Arrays thanks to the optimization of PHP 5.5 and arrays.
3. stdClass is evil.
4. Class still uses less memory than Arrays. (about 30-40% less!!).
5. SplFixedArray is similar to use a Class but it uses more memory.

Comment: A well done to you good sir. Would be interesting to expand this out to nested arrays, etc. Interesting sites for other PHP performance: http://www.phpbench.com/ http://www.php-benchmark-script.com/ but I like that you used memory as well.

Comment: With PHP7 the difference between arrays and objects became more significant. You script shows a difference of 30% runtime and 60% memory. Thats just my machine, but as a rule of thumb: Don't use arrays as structs. Use objects instead :)

Comment: Are objects different than classes in this case?

Comment: Bookmarking this in hopes of any PHP7 update. And the perhaps the upcoming PHP8, when applicable. @magallanes

Comment: Please note that if you use a class with `getters` and `setters`, the performance drops significantly (approximately 8.5x slower than array under PHP 8.1).

Answer (score 10):

magallanes' script @ **PHP 7.3.5**

- `SomeClass Object` is fastest and lightest.
- `Array` **1.32x** speed. **2.70x** memory.
- `stdClass Object` **1.65x** speed. **2.94x** memory.

Raw output:

```
arrays: 0.064794063568115
memory: 444920
Array (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.048975944519043
memory: 164512
SomeClass Object (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.081161022186279
memory: 484416
stdClass Object (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

Answer (score 8):

I used this code for "profiling" (1000 instances, 1000.000 reads/writes):

```
function p($i) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($i);
  echo '</pre>';
}


$t0 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $z = array();
    for ($j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
        $z['aaa'] = 'aaa';
        $z['bbb'] = 'bbb';
        $z['ccc'] = $z['aaa'].$z['bbb'];
    }
}
echo '<p>arrays: '.(microtime(true) - $t0);
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<1000; $i++) {
    $z = (object) null;
    for ($j=0; $j<1000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;
    }
}
echo '<p>obj: '.(microtime(true) - $t0);
p($z);

echo '<p> phpversion '.phpversion();
```

It outputs in my LINUX hosting this stuff:

```
arrays: 1.1085488796234

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
obj: 1.2824709415436

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
phpversion 5.2.17
```

so in a conclusion: **objects are slower even on PHP 5.2. Don't use objects unless you really need their oop features.**

Comment: from user levans http://stackoverflow.com/users/1473035/levans: I ran this with 5.3.8 and objects were slower, 0.51839280128479 for arrays vs 0.85355806350708 for objects. I also ran it on 5.4.13 and got the opposite results, likely due to the class optimizations done in 5.4, 0.6256799697876 for arrays vs 0.43650078773499. Thus it looks like the tables have turned and objects are now the way to go.

Comment: Good answer, i just tested on XAMPP(Apache) and got the results below:
arrays: 0.5174868106842

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
obj: 0.72189617156982

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
phpversion 5.4.19

Comment: I also ran on 5.4.13, but got the opposite of Jean-Bernard Pellerin:

Arrays: 0.5020840167999
Objects: 1.0378720760345

So I wouldn't commit to objects just yet.

Comment: I did some changes in the code and Class is fast than Arrays for php 5.4 (5.4.16 32bits Windows).  I put a new answer that explains the reason.

Comment: PHP 5.5.11 Results: Arrays: 0.17430, Objects: 0.24183

Comment: PHP 7.0 ::::: Arrays: 0.58 vs. Obj: 0.59

Comment: arrays: 0.538612127304
obj: 0.488164186478
phpversion 7.0.8

Answer (score 6):

Well I got curious today based off of @magallanes benchmark, so I expanded it a bit. I upped some of the for loops to really highlight the gaps between things. This is running on Apache 2.4, mod_php, and PHP 7.2.

Here's a summary table to make the results easier:

```
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------+
|           Test            | Memory  |      Time       |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------+
| Array                     | 2305848 | 9.5637300014496 |
| stdClass                  | 2505824 | 11.212271928787 |
| SomeClass                 |  963640 | 11.558017015457 | <-- *
| AnotherClass              | 2563136 | 10.872401237488 |
| SetterClass               |  905848 | 59.879059791565 |
| SetterClassDefineReturn   |  905792 | 60.484427213669 |
| SetterClassSetFromParam   |  745792 | 62.783381223679 |
| SetterClassSetKeyAndParam |  745824 | 72.155715942383 |
+---------------------------+---------+-----------------+
* - Winner winner chicken dinner
```

Below is the modified script. I wanted to test setting properties with methods and defining types. I was very surprised to find that using setter methods adds a significant hit to the code. Now granted this is a very very specific performance test where many apps will not even hit this. But if you have a site that handles 1000/reqs/second with 1000 classes that are used with 1000s of objects, you can see how this may affect performance.

```php
<?php

set_time_limit(500);

class SomeClass {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;
}
    
class AnotherClass {
}

class SetterClass {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;

    public function setAAA() {
        $this->aaa = 'aaa';
    }

    public function setBBB() {
        $this->bbb = 'bbb';
    }

    public function setCCC() {
        $this->ccc = $this->aaa.$this->bbb;
    }
}

class SetterClassDefineReturn {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;

    public function setAAA():void {
        $this->aaa = 'aaa';
    }

    public function setBBB():void {
        $this->bbb = 'bbb';
    }

    public function setCCC():void {
        $this->ccc = $this->aaa.$this->bbb;
    }
}

class SetterClassSetFromParam {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;

    public function setAAA(string $val): void {
        $this->aaa = $val;
    }

    public function setBBB(string $val): void {
        $this->bbb = $val;
    }

    public function setCCC(string $val): void {
        $this->ccc = $val;
    }
}

class SetterClassSetKeyAndParam {
    public $aaa;
    public $bbb;
    public $ccc;

    public function set(string $key, string $val): void {
        $this->{$key} = $val;
    }
}

function p($i) {
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($i);
  echo '</pre>';
  echo '<hr>';
}

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new SomeClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new AnotherClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new SetterClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->setAAA();
        $z->setBBB();
        $z->setCCC();          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new SetterClassDefineReturn();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->setAAA();
        $z->setBBB();
        $z->setCCC();          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new SetterClassSetFromParam();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->setAAA('aaa');
        $z->setBBB('bbb');
        $z->setCCC('aaabbb');          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';

p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new SetterClassSetKeyAndParam();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->set('aaa', 'aaa');
        $z->set('bbb', 'bbb');  
        $z->set('ccc', 'aaabbb');        
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);

$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = new stdClass();
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z->aaa = 'aaa';
        $z->bbb = 'bbb';
        $z->ccc = $z->aaa.$z->bbb;          
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z); 


$t0 = microtime(true);
$arraysOf=[];
$inicio=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<5000; $i++) {
    $z = [];
    for ($j=0; $j<5000; $j++) {
        $z['aaa'] = 'aaa';
        $z['bbb'] = 'bbb';
        $z['ccc'] = $z['aaa'].$z['bbb'];            
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$fin=memory_get_usage();    
echo '<p>Time Taken (seconds): '.(microtime(true) - $t0).'</p>';
echo '<p>Memory: '.($fin-$inicio).'</p>';
p($z);
```

And here's the results:

```
Time Taken (seconds): 11.558017015457

Memory: 963640

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

-----

Time Taken (seconds): 10.872401237488

Memory: 2563136

AnotherClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 59.879059791565

Memory: 905848

SetterClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 60.484427213669

Memory: 905792

SetterClassDefineReturn Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 62.783381223679

Memory: 745792

SetterClassSetFromParam Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 72.155715942383

Memory: 745824

SetterClassSetKeyAndParam Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 11.212271928787

Memory: 2505824

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

----

Time Taken (seconds): 9.5637300014496

Memory: 2305848

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I use magallanes' code under php 7.0.9 :

```
arrays: 0.19802498817444

memory: 324672

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.18602299690247

memory: 132376

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.1950249671936

memory: 348296

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

And user php 7.1.3:

```
arrays: 0.59932994842529
memory: 444920
Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 0.72895789146423
memory: 164512

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)

arrays: 0.61777496337891
memory: 484416
stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

Comment: And don't forget stdClass can use real string numeric key. ['1'=>1] will be stored as [1=>1], but we can use `$a=new stdClass(); $a->{1} = 1; $b=(array)$a;` get real ['1'=>1].

Comment: So, in conclusion.. Arrays are 18% faster but consume 2.7x as much memory.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody who is still interested in this question :) 
I ran Quazzle code on PHP 7.1 Ubuntu x64 and got this answer:

```
arrays: 0.24848890304565

memory: 444920

Array
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.23238587379456

memory: 164512

SomeClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
arrays: 0.24422693252563

memory: 484416

stdClass Object
(
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

### Conclusion

Array take **4**(!) the memory than class object.
Class object marginally faster.
**stdClass still evil** © magallanes :)

Comment: Dynamically added properties are not much different than array in terms of memory. But pure data structure (declared public fields, none dynamic) is way more memmory efficient. I wander what will hapen if you take SomeClass and remove public $ccc and let it be declared dynamically will it take the same memory as AnotherClass .

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown us the code for how `$object->value` works, as it could be that backend it is an array in which case *theoretically* using an array would be faster as it involves one less function call. The cost of doing the lookup will probably be huge compared to the function call. If it is a variable, there is going to be very little diffrence as objects and arrays in PHP have a very similar implementation.

If you are looking at optimizations, you will need to profile to check where the majority of the time is being used. I suspect that changing objects to arrays will make no major difference.

Comment: I assumed that value would be a public variable, therefore defenitely O(1) while the hash-lookup might not be.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is kind of an old post so I thought I'll update it.
here are my codes and stats, done on Zend CE 5.3.21
I tried to test the whole thing, storing info and pulling it back.

V1 : takes 0.83 sec

```
for ($i=1; $i<1000000; $i++) {
  $a = get_one();
  $b = $a[0];
  $b = $a[1];
}

function get_one() {
  return array(1,1);
}
```

V2 : takes 3.05 sec

```
for ($i=1; $i<1000000; $i++) {
  $a = get_one();
  $b = $a->v;
  $b = $a->k;
}

function get_one() {
  $ret = new test();
  $ret->v = 1;
  $reb->k = 1;
  return $ret;
}

class test {
  public $v;
  public $k;
}
```

V3 : takes 1.98 sec (note that the constructor improves the performance)

```
for ($i=1; $i<1000000; $i++) {
  $a = get_one();
  $b = $a->v;
  $b = $a->k;
}

function get_one() {
  return new test(1,1);
}

class test {
  public $v;
  public $k;
  public function __construct($v, $k) {
    $this->v = $v;
    $this->k = $k;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the PHP-source code for micro-performance-features like that.

But at a first glance, no doing ['value'] will not be faster because PHP needs to do a Lookup on where to find ['value'] even thougn a hashtable lookup should be O(1), that's not guaranteed. There's more overhead when you use Text-index.

If the object only contains 1 variables that you need to access which is value, there's more overhead in using an object.

Comment: And where do you think properties are looked up? They're in a hash table, too... (though this is only more or less true in trunk).

Answer (score 0):

If Arrays and Classs are the same performance, I think use objects of predefined classes for storing/passing business data would make our program more logic and the code more readability.

Today, with modern ide like Eclipse, Netbean ... it's very convenient to know what info an objects (of predefined class) is carrying but arrays are not so

Eg:
With array

```
function registerCourse(array $student) {
    // Right here I don't know how a $student look like unless doing a print_r() or var_dump()
 ....
}
```

With object

```
class Studen {
    private $_name, $_age;
    public function getAge() {}
    public function getName() {}
    ..
}

function registerCourse(Studen $student) {
    // Right here I just Ctrl+Space $student or click "Student" and I know I can get name or age from it
    ...
}
```

Comment: This contradicts the other proven answers and has no proof. So this is more an ideological belief, than an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair it depends on what sort of data You have. The results in other answers are (more or less)* correct. I'll paste in the test code on the bottom for clarity.

The important thing here is that You can save a fair amount of memory if you use a predefined object, the trade-off is the fact that you need to define the exact structure.

Consider the following test results:

```
static obj: 0.04223108291626
memory: 164920
object(staticSet)#1 (3) {
  ["aaa"]=>
  string(3) "aaa"
  ["bbb"]=>
  string(3) "bbb"
  ["ccc"]=>
  string(6) "aaabbb"
}
---------------------------------------
static obj with an additional prop: 0.042968988418579
memory: 524920
object(staticSet2)#1000 (3) {
  ["aaa"]=>
  string(3) "aaa"
  ["bbb"]=>
  string(3) "bbb"
  ["ddd"]=>
  string(6) "aaabbb"
}
---------------------------------------
```

I might be wrong here, I'm did not look into the PHP source but I believe that as far as PHP is concerned, everything is an array. A predefined object is just a well defined array. An interesting note is that the value type does not have an effect ie. a string value of '1' will take up the same amount of memory as a bool value of true.

Why? Well as I stated before PHP is arrays so if you have an object with a setter function what (a simplified version) PHP does is this:

```
$objects = ['objectName' => [
    'aaa' => '',
    'bbb' => '',
    'ccc' => '',
    'setValue:f' => function('name', 'value') { ... }
    ]
];
```

Every time you execute, you do a lookup for the function key that does a lookup for a prop name, plus any validation for prop type etc. in the background. The memory savings in a predefined object come from defining an array of a set length (otherwise impossible in PHP) instead of allocating a chunk of memory.

Conclusion:

**Static objects:** Yey! We save memory! But if you try to add anything outside the definition it will grow larger then a stdClass.

```
['aaa'] into [['aaa'],['bbb']]
```

**Arrays:** If You write in PHP You better love them, even a string is an array of characters in PHP.

**Objects:** Objects have cool functionality, they're a wonderful way to keep your code organised, clean, modular. But as we all know "with great power...".

Finally, my test code and the '*'. people seem to forget that if You don't clean up your variables while the script is running they will remain in the memory, while it will not impact the execution time (much), it will impact the memory measurement. So while running a memory profiling unset() is your friend.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$noOfObjects = 1000;
$noOfOperations = 1000;

class set {
    public function setKey($key, $value) {
        $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
    public function readKey($name) {
        return $this->{$name};
    }
}

class staticSet {
    public string $aaa;
    public string $bbb;
    public string $ccc;
}

class staticSet2 {
    public string $aaa;
    public string $bbb;
}

class staticSet3 {
    public bool $aaa;
    public bool $bbb;
    public bool $ccc;
}

$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = array(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z['aaa'] = 'aaa';
        $z['bbb'] = 'bbb';
        $z['ccc'] = $z['aaa'].$z['bbb'];
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'arrays: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new set(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->setKey('aaa','aaa');
        $z->setKey('bbb','bbb');
        $z->setKey('ccc',$z->readKey('aaa').$z->readKey('bbb'));
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'dynamic obj: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new staticSet(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->{'aaa'} = 'aaa';
        $z->{'bbb'} = 'bbb';
        $z->{'ccc'} = $z->{'aaa'}.$z->{'bbb'};
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'static obj: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new staticSet2(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->{'aaa'} = 'aaa';
        $z->{'bbb'} = 'bbb';
        $z->{'ddd'} = $z->{'aaa'}.$z->{'bbb'};
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'static obj with an additional prop: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime($noOfObjects);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new Ds\Map(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->put('aaa','aaa');
        $z->put('bbb','bbb');
        $z->put('ccc',$z->get('aaa').$z->get('bbb'));
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'Ds\Map: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new staticSet(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->{'aaa'} = '1';
        $z->{'bbb'} = '1';
        $z->{'ccc'} = ($z->{'aaa'} && $z->{'bbb'});
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'static obj with bool values: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = new staticSet3(); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z->{'aaa'} = '1';
        $z->{'bbb'} = '1';
        $z->{'ccc'} = ($z->{'aaa'} && $z->{'bbb'});
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'static obj with defined bool values: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;
$arraysOf=[];
$t0 = microtime(true);
$start=memory_get_usage(); 
for ($i=0; $i<$noOfObjects; $i++) {
    $z = array('aaa' => '','bbb' => '','ccc' => ''); // definition
    for ($j=0; $j<$noOfOperations; $j++) {
        $z['aaa'] = 'aaa';
        $z['bbb'] = 'bbb';
        $z['ccc'] = $z['aaa'].$z['bbb'];
    }
    $arraysOf[]=$z;
}
$end=memory_get_usage();  
echo 'predefined array: '.(microtime(true) - $t0).PHP_EOL;
echo 'memory: '.($end-$start).PHP_EOL;
var_dump($z);
unset($t0,$start,$end,$z,$arraysOf);
echo '---------------------------------------'.PHP_EOL;


echo 'phpversion '.phpversion().PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

@magallanes script on PHP 8.2.5 (built: Apr 12 2023)

- plain data objects are still the fastest and lightest:

  - sequential arrays are very close in speed
  - if you add a constructor to it it will become the lowest but using less memory
- associative array takes 1.26x speed, 2.89x memory
- stdClass Object takes 1.16x speed, 3.15x memory

```
arrays: 0.048079967498779
memory: 428536

Array (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
-----------------------------------

arrays: 0.037950038909912
memory: 148128

SomeClass Object (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
---------------------------------------

arrays: 0.044036865234375
memory: 468032

stdClass Object (
    [aaa] => aaa
    [bbb] => bbb
    [ccc] => aaabbb
)
```

**Sequential arrays:** very close to plain data objects but still those objects are better both in performance and memory.

```
sequantial arrays set by index: 0.0399329662323
memory: 268536

Array (
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => bbb
    [2] => aaabbb
)
```

**Objects with constructors:** apparently it is better to avoid them, execution time is nearly doubled.

```
class with ctor: 0.072697162628174
memory: 116128

SomeClassWithCtor Object (
    [aaa:SomeClassWithCtor:private] => aaa
    [bbb:SomeClassWithCtor:private] => bbb
    [ccc:SomeClassWithCtor:private] => aaabbb
)
```