# Is there any performance benefit of using objects in php?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, object

Recently i was researching that topic, some of the article writers claimed that because of the php's oop and class systems are actually hacks and hooks and therefore php is a scripting language.

I was wondering how that reflects on performance side.

Is there any significant performance differences between arrays and objects ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193049/php-objects-vs-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using php5 an object is slightly faster than an array but in most cases the difference is negligible

Here is a link to a performance test:
http://aggregation.novaak.net/?q=node/227

Comment: I'd consider your statement a lie, and the reference you give does not make it better.