# PHP array difference in value geting

Tags: php, arrays, difference

Can someone explain to me by the most easiest way possible difference between following? After reading about PHP arrays, i still dont get it.

```
print $myArray[0]->token
```

and

```
print $myArray[0]["token"]
```

**Edit**:

Question is not about best approach, but about meaning of that. Answer can be fond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521479), but it is not direct answer to my question

Comment: In the first expression, there is an object on the 0 index of $myArray, in the second, it is an array.

Comment: Marcell give most simple answer. Remember that second example can also contain object on key 0 that implements array access

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Variable vs Array vs Object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521479/php-variable-vs-array-vs-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. An **object** inside an array having `token` element
2. An **array** inside an array having `token` element

Answer (score 2):

An example of all this :

```
<?php

    //Creating simple object

    $bookObject = new stdClass;
    $bookObject->title = "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban";

    //Adding object to books array
    $books = array($bookObject);//this array is equivalent to your $myArray

    //Acessing object using -> operator
    echo $books[0]->title;

    //Re-initializng books array
    $books = array(0=>array("title" => "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban"));

     //Accessing elements of an array by key
    echo $books[0]['title'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$myArray` is an array having an **object** with the **property** (*attribute*, *variable*) named `token` as its first element.
2. `$myArray` is an array having an **associative array** with the **key** named `token` as its first element.

So, it's about two different data structures that the array is holding as the first element indexed by 0.