# Whats is the difference between -> and [''] in php

Tags: php

I have been following 2 ways to get data from an array..sometimes i use

```
$username=      $data['username'];
$first_name=    $data['first_name'];
```

and sometimes,

```
$username=      $data->username;
$first_name=    $data->first_name;
```

Anytime i have an array, i know 1 of them will work, and it works..

but i am unable to understand what is the difference between them, I am never sure which one to use.

I google it a lot but unable to find any explanation.

Kindly guide me

Thanks

Comment: One of them is a array the other is a object

Comment: The first is an array, the second is an object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521479/php-variable-vs-array-vs-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a misconception.

The upper syntax with square brackets will only work for arrays (or objects implementing `ArrayAccess`).

The lower syntax using the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` will only work on objects. You cannot access arrays like that.

Compare the following links in the PHP manual:

- http://php.net/arrays
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: can you also tell , what is the difference between `->` and `=>`

Comment: @Kirmani88 the Reference your question got closed with is a great resource. Check it, please.

Comment: Thanks! I just go through the reference links and it helped a lot :)